# Error Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0 at gestionDesposito.main(gestionDesposito.java:13)

Tags: java, array, arraylist

No se muy bien como solucionar este error(creo que es por que no apunto bien a la posición del array pero no tengo mucha idea de como arreglarlo).

```
import java.util.*;
public class gestionDesposito {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int tamanio=0;
    Deposito[] d=new Deposito[tamanio];
    Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in);

  System.out.println("Escriba el numero de despositos a crear entre 4 y 10: ");
  tamanio=sc.nextInt();
  if(tamanio>=4 && tamanio<=10){
      for(int i=0;i<tamanio;i++){
          d[i]=new Deposito("0001",10,30);
          System.out.println(d[i]);
      }

  }

  sc.close();
}

}
```

Comment: No Le Estas Asignando El Valor Al Array Debes, Indicarle Primero Al Usuario Que Inserte La Longitud Del Array Declara una Variable Y Pidele que te ingrese el valor y despues la longitud que el te solicito pon la variable dentro de los corchetes del array y listo te va a funcionar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
int tamanio=0;
Deposito[] d=new Deposito[tamanio];
```

Estás creando un array de longitud 1. Y después si introducimos un "5" por la consola estás intentando acceder a un array de longitud 5.

Es decir, pides al usuario que te indique la longitud, pero no se la estás asignado al array.

**Solución:** Tendrías que ponerlo después del Scanner:

```
int tamanio=0;
Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in);

  System.out.println("Escriba el numero de despositos a crear entre 4 y 10: ");
  tamanio=sc.nextInt();
Deposito[] d=new Deposito[tamanio];
```

Nota: Si quieres que el tamaño del array sea de la misma longitud que la que indica el usuario, réstale 1 a la variable `tamanio`. Ya que si introduce un 5, un `array[5]` tiene 6 posiciones.